# Error: 9245, Severity: 16, State: 1. / During the last time interval XXX query notification errors were suppressed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker

I've got this sequence of error messages showing up regularly in my server error log:

> *Error: 9245, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>
>   During the last time interval 257 query notification errors were suppressed.*

But I cannot find any specifics on Error 9245. I've looked at the spid that is generating the error, and it's related to the service broker. I also have errors like these showing up regularly, and I suspect they are all related:

> *The query notification dialog on conversation handle '{1C8BCD7B-3366-E211-93C7-005056BA3606}.' closed due to the following
>   error:
>
>   `<?xml version="1.0"?>`
>
>   `<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error">`
>
>   `<Code>-8490</Code>`
>
>   `<Description>Cannot find the remote service &apos;SqlQueryNotificationService-b7240bb0-6586-4cee-bb7c-a3d2e706c0f8&apos; because it does not exist.</Description>`
>   `</Error>`*

That error is one we have known about for a while, but haven't been able to resolve in our application code as of yet. The first two errors have just started showing up in the last few days though, and both the frequency of the errors and the number of query notifications that are being suppressed seem to be increasing.

Does anyone have any insight on further troubleshooting steps, or information on Error 9245?

Edit: Some additional information -

Regarding Jon's question, we are implementing SqlDependency in the App, and I believe it may not be done correctly, resulting in the query notification dialog messages. When we previously ran this application on SQL 2008R2 we enabled trace flag 4133 as outlined in this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958006 which at least alleviated the number of messages that were occuring in the event log.

That said, the first sequence of error messages that I posted above (Error: 9245) are new (to my knowledge). We upgraded the server to SQL 2012 SP1 a few weeks back and had NOT enabled trace flag 4133 as of the time that the 9245 error started showing up.

Also of note, while the errors were occurring with increasing frequency (nearing 1 error every five to ten minutes) for approximately a 12 hour period they stopped abruptly yesterday morning shortly after I asked here about Error: 9245. About an hour after that I enabled trace flag 4133, and I have not seen the error since. While it seems the two errors are related, I'm not entirely sure they're directly connected.

I'm going to see what I can find from other windows event logs on this server and see if anything else correlates to the times these errors occur. I've also disabled 4133 to confirm that it has not had an effect on the 9245 error.

Edit2: Minutes after disabling trace flag 4133 the errors have begun occurring again, and I believe I know the relation between the two now as well, so I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question.

Comment: Are you using [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) in your application? If yes, I would say it's not implemented correctly.

Comment: @JonSeigel, yes we are using SqlDependency, and quite possibly incorrectly. I've added some additional information to the question regarding that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error 9245 message appears to be directly connected to the 'The query notification dialog on conversation handle...' message in that SQL Server 2012 SP1 appears to only show that error a maximum of 10 times (with the same timestamp) in the error log, the rest are aggregated into a single error message:

> During the last time interval 257 query notification errors were suppressed.

Which is preceded by the message:

> Error: 9245, Severity: 16, State: 1.

Prior to SQL 2012 I do not believe the error notifications were aggregated at all, and did not result in a severity 16 error.

Comment: And now the real work of fixing the application can begin. :) Good luck.