# Error: 9245, Severity: 16, State: 1. / "During the last time interval X query notification errors were suppressed"

Tags: sql-server, errors

We are receiving this notification several hundred times a day and while we're regularly checking notifications from Severity 16 errors, this isn't something we're really concerned about.

I've read the article and replies at [Error: 9245, Severity: 16, State: 1. / During the last time interval XXX query notification errors were suppressed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33750/error-9245-severity-16-state-1-during-the-last-time-interval-xxx-query-n) and while that's very informative, I'd like to know how can we suppress it?

We have an automated alert set up for severity 016 errors and we don't exact categorize this one as an "action items" yet are receiving hundreds of them daily.

Is there a way to suppress it?

Comment: So you have an automated alert (have not told us how or what this is) and you have it set to alert on Sev 16 errors, and you want us to tell you how to suppress Sev 16 errors?

Comment: A mailbox rule?

Answer (score 0):

It's the simple built-in alerts that you can configure in SQL Server i.e. (EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @params) - it emails the DBA team when that error is captured.

Since this particular "cause"  is not exactly threatening the health of the server I was wondering "other than a mailbox rule" if there was a way to "omit" these particular ones containing "notification errors were suppressed" - so basically that they're not sent at all.